# Suitable widget for drawing a 2D cartesian coordinate system in java

Tags: java, user-interface, resolution, cartesian

I want to build up a GUI area where users can click randomly. Then I want to retrieve the cartesian (x,y) coordinates of those points where the user clicked. Which GUI component is suitable for my task. Also, I want to have any point as big as a usual dot (maybe 3 pixels or more - does this depend on resolution? And if I change the screen resolution of the monitor during the program execution, does the coordinate change?)

I usually work in web programming and I am totally novice in this area. Any pointers to good background reading would help greatly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html
Is this what you're searching for?

as for changing resolution,
I believe you need a listener which changes/updates the size, though I'm pretty much not familiar with that, sorry.